# Get certain data from text - Java

Tags: java, string

I am creating a bukkit plugin for minecraft and i need to know a few things before i move on.
I want to check if a text has this layout: "B:10 S:5" for example.
It stands for Buy:amount and Sell:amount
How can i check the easiest way if it follows the syntax? 
It can be any number that is 0 or over.

Another problem is to get this data out of the text. how can i check what text is after B: and S: and return it as an integer

I have not tried out this yet because i have no idea where to start.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the simple problem you gave, you can get away with a simple answer. Otherwise, see the regex answer below.

```
boolean test(String str){
try{
//String str = "B:10 S:5";
String[] arr = str.split(" ");//split to left and right of space = [B:10,S:5]
String[] bArr = arr[0].split(":");//split ...first colon = [B,10]
String[] sArr = arr[1].split(":");//... second colon = [S,5]

//need to use try/catch here in case the string is not an int value.
String labelB = bArr[0];
Integer b = Integer.parseInt(bArr[1]);
String labelS = sArr[0];
Integer s = Integer.parseInt(sArr[1]);
}catch( Exception e){return false;}
return true;
}
```

See my answer here for a related task. More related details below.
[How can I parse a string for a set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660257/how-can-i-parse-a-string-for-a-set/26660984#26660984)

Essentially, you need to use regex and iterate through the groups. Just in case the grammar is not always B and S, I made this more abstract.Also, if there are extra white spaces in the middle for what ever reason, I made that more broad too. The pattern says there are 4 groups (indicated by parentheses): label1, number1, label2, and number2. + means 1 or more. [] means a set of characters. a-z is a range of characters (don't put anything between A-Z and a-z). There are also other ways of showing alpha and numeric patterns, but these are easier to read.

```
//this is expensive    
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z]+):([0-9]+)[ ]+([A-Za-z]+):([0-9]+)");


    boolean test(String txt){
        Matcher m=p.matcher(txt);
        if(!m.matches())return false;
        int groups=m.groupCount();//should only equal 5 (default whole match+4 groups) here, but you can test this

        System.out.println("Matched: " + m.group(0));
         //Label1 = m.group(1);
         //val1 = m.group(2);
         //Label2 = m.group(3);
         //val2 = m.group(4);

       return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked nice! but you wrote that this is expensive, what do you mean with that?

Comment: Compiling a pattern is actually a very expensive operation. Just make sure you are doing it once and not multiple times. Make it static or just keep it out of a loop, function call, and repeatable initialization code of a class. If you have a small program, performance might not be a big deal, but keep these things in mind. Calling matcher has more of a cost than the naive way I gave at the top because it does the parsing. Lots of branching (if/switch statements). With complex problems, regex is the best by far.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Regular Expression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

In your case,`^B:(\d)+ S:(\d)+$` is enough.

In java, to use a regular expression:

```
public class RegExExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^B:(\d)+ S:(\d)+$");
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
            if (p.matcher(args[i]).matches())
                System.out.println( "ARGUMENT #" + i + " IS VALID!")
            else
                System.out.println( "ARGUMENT #" + i + " IS INVALID!");
    }
}
```

This sample program take inputs from command line, validate it against the pattern and print the result to STDOUT.